# Google account auto Login and get access token using php

Tags: php, google-api, youtube-api, google-api-php-client

I am using You tube API for live streaming in my application. For scheduling the live streaming I will give the one common email id and password for every users.

I need to login the user into google account automatically( Without giving the email id and password) using the common email id and password and get access token using php.

Is it possible?

My current code is below.please suggest one solution!!

```
<?php

// Call set_include_path() as needed to point to your client library.
require_once 'Google/autoload.php';
require_once 'Google/Client.php';
require_once 'Google/Service/YouTube.php';
session_start();

/*
 * You can acquire an OAuth 2.0 client ID and client secret from the
 * Google Developers Console <https://console.developers.google.com/>
 * For more information about using OAuth 2.0 to access Google APIs, please see:
 * <https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/authentication>
 * Please ensure that you have enabled the YouTube Data API for your project.
 */
$OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID = '$OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID';
$OAUTH2_CLIENT_SECRET = '$OAUTH2_CLIENT_SECRET';
$htmlBody="";
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setClientId($OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID);
$client->setClientSecret($OAUTH2_CLIENT_SECRET);
$client->setScopes('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube');
$redirect = filter_var('http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'],
    FILTER_SANITIZE_URL);
$client->setRedirectUri($redirect);

// Define an object that will be used to make all API requests.
$youtube = new Google_Service_YouTube($client);

if (isset($_GET['code'])) {
  if (strval($_SESSION['state']) !== strval($_GET['state'])) {
    die('The session state did not match.');
  }

  $client->authenticate($_GET['code']);
  $_SESSION['token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
  header('Location: ' . $redirect);
}

if (isset($_SESSION['token'])) {
  $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['token']);
}

// Check to ensure that the access token was successfully acquired.
if ($client->getAccessToken()) {
if(isset($_POST['title']) && isset($_POST['timeStart']) && isset($_POST['timeEnd']) && isset($_POST['Status']))
{
  try {
    // Create an object for the liveBroadcast resource's snippet. Specify values
    // for the snippet's title, scheduled start time, and scheduled end time.
    $broadcastSnippet = new Google_Service_YouTube_LiveBroadcastSnippet();
    $broadcastSnippet->setTitle($_POST['title']);
    $broadcastSnippet->setScheduledStartTime($_POST['timeStart']);
    $broadcastSnippet->setScheduledEndTime($_POST['timeEnd']);

    // Create an object for the liveBroadcast resource's status, and set the
    // broadcast's status to "private".
    $status = new Google_Service_YouTube_LiveBroadcastStatus();
    $status->setPrivacyStatus($_POST['Status']);

    // Create the API request that inserts the liveBroadcast resource.
    $broadcastInsert = new Google_Service_YouTube_LiveBroadcast();
    $broadcastInsert->setSnippet($broadcastSnippet);
    $broadcastInsert->setStatus($status);
    $broadcastInsert->setKind('youtube#liveBroadcast');

    // Execute the request and return an object that contains information
    // about the new broadcast.
    $broadcastsResponse = $youtube->liveBroadcasts->insert('snippet,status',
        $broadcastInsert, array());

    // Create an object for the liveStream resource's snippet. Specify a value
    // for the snippet's title.
    $streamSnippet = new Google_Service_YouTube_LiveStreamSnippet();
    $streamSnippet->setTitle('New Stream');

    // Create an object for content distribution network details for the live
    // stream and specify the stream's format and ingestion type.
    $cdn = new Google_Service_YouTube_CdnSettings();
    $cdn->setFormat("1080p");
    $cdn->setIngestionType('rtmp');

    // Create the API request that inserts the liveStream resource.
    $streamInsert = new Google_Service_YouTube_LiveStream();
    $streamInsert->setSnippet($streamSnippet);
    $streamInsert->setCdn($cdn);
    $streamInsert->setKind('youtube#liveStream');

    // Execute the request and return an object that contains information
    // about the new stream.
    $streamsResponse = $youtube->liveStreams->insert('snippet,cdn',
        $streamInsert, array());

    // Bind the broadcast to the live stream.
    $bindBroadcastResponse = $youtube->liveBroadcasts->bind(
        $broadcastsResponse['id'],'id,contentDetails',
        array(
            'streamId' => $streamsResponse['id'],
        ));

    $htmlBody .= "<h3>Added Broadcast</h3><ul>";
    $htmlBody .= sprintf('<li>%s published at %s (%s)</li>',
        $broadcastsResponse['snippet']['title'],
        $broadcastsResponse['snippet']['publishedAt'],
        $broadcastsResponse['id']);
    $htmlBody .= '</ul>';
    $htmlBody .= "<h3>Added Stream</h3><ul>";
    $htmlBody .= sprintf('<li>%s (%s)</li>',
        $streamsResponse['snippet']['title'],
        $streamsResponse['id']);
    $htmlBody .= '</ul>';
    $htmlBody .= "<h3>Bound Broadcast</h3><ul>";
    $htmlBody .= sprintf('<li>Broadcast (%s) was bound to stream (%s).</li>',
        $bindBroadcastResponse['id'],
        $bindBroadcastResponse['contentDetails']['boundStreamId']);
    $htmlBody .= '</ul>';
    //$htmlBody .="<h3>Live  Broadcast</h3><div>";

    //$htmlBody .= sprintf("<iframe id='ytplayer' type='text/html' width='640' height='390' src='http://www.youtube.com/embed/%s?autoplay=1'  frameborder='0'></iframe>",
        //  $broadcastsResponse['id']);
    $htmlBody .= '</div>';


  } catch (Google_Service_Exception $e) {
    $htmlBody .= sprintf('<p>A service error occurred: <code>%s</code></p>',
        htmlspecialchars($e->getMessage()));
      // echo $e->getMessage();
  } catch (Google_Exception $e) {
    $htmlBody .= sprintf('<p>An client error occurred: <code>%s</code></p>',
        htmlspecialchars($e->getMessage()));
  }

  $_SESSION['token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
  } else {
  if(isset($_GET['propid']))
  {
  $htmlBody = <<<END
  <form action="" method="post">
<input type="text" name="title" value="Event Title"/><br/>
<input type="text" name="timeStart" value="Start Time"/><br/>
<input type="text" name="timeEnd" value="End Time"/><br/>
<input type="text" name="Status" value="Public,Unlisted,Private"/>
<input type ="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
END;
} else {

 $htmlBody = <<<END
 <p>Close this window and click the schedule button for live streaming</p>
<p>You need to <a href="#"  onclick="window.close();">Close Window</a> before proceeding.<p>
END;

}

}
} else {
  // If the user hasn't authorized the app, initiate the OAuth flow
  $state = mt_rand();
  $client->setState($state);
  $_SESSION['state'] = $state;

  $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
  $htmlBody = <<<END
  <h3>Authorization Required</h3>
  <p>You need to <a href="$authUrl" onclick="window.open('$authUrl', 'newwindow', 'width=600, height=400'); return false;">authorize access</a> before proceeding.<p>
END;
}
?>

<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Bound Live Broadcast</title>
</head>
<body>
  <?=$htmlBody?>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Loging in to an API using a login and password is called client login

ClientLogin was been officially deprecated since [April 20, 2012](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/auth-migration#timetable) and is now no longer available. Requests to ClientLogin will fail with a HTTP 404 response.

Answer: No it is not possible to programmatically access the YouTube API using a users login and password.  The only way to access private data owned by a user though the YouTube API is to use Oauth2.

Comment: I have only one user account for all users to schedule live stream. The schedule will only available after user login. user no need to give the google account login for schedule live stream. is it possible through the php?

Comment: yes but I don't have a working example.   Authenticate your code once use $client->setAccessType('offline'); to get the refresh token save the refresh token. then use the refreshtoken to get an access token and with out logging in again.